# SDP based heuristics for graph coloring

Tags: reference-request, graph-colorings, semidefinite-programming

This is a question about semidefinite programming heuristics for graph vertex coloring based on the Lovasz theta number such as "Approximate Graph Coloring" by Karger, Motwani and Sudan or "A semidefinite programming based heuristic for graph coloring" by Dukanovic and Rendl.

Given a graph with 1) $\chi(G) = \omega(G)$ and the property that 2) in all optimal colorings of G with $\omega(G)$ colors, there are two fixed non-adjacent vertices $u,v \in V(G)$ that do not receive the same color, i.e., $\forall c: V(G) \rightarrow [\omega(G)]$, $c(u) \neq c(v)$. Does every optimal solution $X$ to the $\theta(\bar{G})$ (=$\omega(G)$) SDP have the property that $X_{u,v} \neq 1$, i.e. can there exist an optimal SDP solution where the two vertices $u,v$ are assigned the same vector?

Maybe to be less specific, i would like to know what is known about the space of solutions to an SDP and its relation to the space of solutions to the original integer program in the case when the two optimal values are equal?